# Escaping parenthesis in PowerShell Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell, escape-characters

Below is a one-line script I am writing that is causing problems when I try to add an open-paran within `invoke-expression`.

Within the script, the file `map.txt` contains 800 lines of 3 digit numbers. The script is intended to change the name of existing files that start with 001..400 (unique/non-repeating) by prefixing a new (unique) three digit number and space before the existing file. To do this, the a three-digit number is extracted from `map.txt` to find the file I want renamed (using `invoke-expression "ls $line1 (*"` and the next line in `map.txt` is the number that should be prefixed to the existing file. So, if the first two lines of `map.txt` are `001` and `008`, the file, `001 (additional characters).ext` (parentheses are part of file name) will be changed to `008 001 (additional characters).ext`

It will execute if I remove the open-paran within `invoke-expression`. However, without the open-paran within invoke-expression, when the `map.txt` file comes to a number pair of `008` `021`, it will try to rename the `008 001 (additional characters).ext` that has already been renamed. Adding the open-paren makes files names unique regardless of name changes that have already occurred and the script should execute as desired. That is, if I can figure out how to include an open-paren within `invoke expression`. I could probably do a work around with a few lines of regex and `-match` but if I can find a quick solution to include the open-paran with `invoke-expression`, it would be ideal.

Thanks for your help.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 800; $i=($i+"2")) {$line1=(get-content ..\map.txt | select -index $i); $line2=(get-content ..\map.txt | select -index ($i+"1")); $old=(invoke-expression 'ls $line1 (*'); $fileold=($old.basename+$old.extension); $filenew=($line2+" "+$fileold); mv "$fileold" "$filenew"}
```

Comment: I would still love a solution. But, I found a quick work around. Using `invoke-expression "ls $line1*"` and creating a new empty subfolder (I called `new`), I changed the move command to `mv $fileold" "new\$filenew"` preventing the script from being able to act upon a file that has already been renamed.

Comment: **_[1]_** why use the dangerous `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet when you can simply rename the file with standard PoSh commands? the `I-E` cmdlet is considered the equivalent of SQL injection in terms of risk. **_[2]_** the term "one liner" means _without any line delimiters_. you have 6 lines inside your `for` loop. [*grin*] **_[3]_** why are you quoting the integers you are adding to your `$I` variable? that is dangerous since you are adding a _char_ to an _int_. yes, PoSh coerces it to an int ... but why use a char for that?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, unless you can add something that is useful you are wasting everyone's time. Not one thing you said helped to address the problem I posed. I would certainly be open to alternative approaches if you had presented any. You clearly like to criticize but not critically criticize as you offer no solutions to make something better. I imagine this is because you aren't loved and feel better about yourself by trying to put down others. As for "one-liners," the accepted definition isn't literally one line of code. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544428/one-liner-vs-script

Comment: you stated that you had a fix, so i was addressing other apparent problems - a _critique_ is what was intended. if you don't want that sort of commentary on your code, flag my comment for removal OR for for moderator attention.

Comment: @Brian Speaking of wasting everyones time... `$line1="001";Invoke-Expression 'ls $line1 (*'` would have been a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and nobody would have ever had to read/understand your file renaming stuff as it is not part of the problem. Anyway, maybe you can get some inspiration from my code [below](https://superuser.com/a/1571398/1077440).

Answer (score 0):

To make `Invoke-Expression 'ls $line1 (*'` or `Invoke-Expression "ls $line1 (*"` work as intended, quote the line you want to pass to `ls` with different quotes, like `Invoke-Expression 'ls "$line1 (*"'` or `Invoke-Expression "ls '$line1 (*'"`.

---

Furthermore, I would like to recommend the following code optimization to you:

```
$numbers = Get-Content -Path "..\map.txt"
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 400; $i++) {
    Get-Item -Path "$($numbers[2*$i]) (*" | ForEach-Object -Process {Rename-Item -Path $_.Name -NewName "$($numbers[2*$i+1]) $($_.Name)"}
}
```

And if you want to squeeze that into one line, you can do it like this:

```
$n=gc ..\map.txt;for($i=0;$i-lt400;$i++){gi "$($n[2*$i]) (*"|%{rni $_ "$($n[2*$i+1]) $($_.Name)"}}
```